# Populate a standard combo box using centura SQLWindows/32

Tags: sql, centura

i want to populate a combo box standard by taking the data from a database using Centura SQLWindows/32, there is any functions for doing that?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize **SalListPopulate( )** function for the same.

bOk = SalListPopulate ( hWndList, hSql, strSelect )

Parameters

hWndList Window Handle. The handle (or name) of the list box or combo box to populate.

hSql Sql Handle. The handle of a SELECT statement.

strSelect String. The SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

For further help / Manuals go here and download the appropriate version:

[Gupta / Centura SQLWindows TeamDeveloper Manuals](http://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=Misc/TD_Books/)